# How can I change the text I am currently typing to be bold with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

`boldBtn.onclick = () => { text.style.fontWeight = "bold" };` causes the whole text to be bold. Including toggling a class named ".bold"

Is it possible to alter text in motion using JavaScript, text that I am currently writing?

See Google docs or Microsoft word bold text feature for an example.

Comment: what's `paragraph`, is it a textarea element?

Comment: I would use a `keyup` Or `keydown` listener instead of `onclick`

Comment: @GrafiCode, Yes paragraph now is **text** is a textarea element

Comment: I don't think you can set bold only to partial text in a textarea (or any input element); in order to do that you need a wyswyg editor, like tinyMCE, which is just like word or google docs

Comment: @ViaTech, Please share a code example?

Comment: Learning to use TinyMCE, this solves the problem, Thank you @GrafiCode